# Laravel Dusk failed to matches url in assertPathIs()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

i try laravel [dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk) today and set up login with modal component. this is my test code

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->browse(function ($browser) {
        $browser->visit('/')
                ->assertSee('My App')
                ->press('Login')
                ->whenAvailable('.modal', function($modal){
                    $modal->type('id','1112')
                        ->type('password','password')
                        ->press('Submit');
                })
                ->assertPathIs('/home');
    });
}
```

when I run dusk command, dusk simulates the login and it works fine. my modal works properly and then redirects to the right page. somehow, my test fails because it says the actual url is still `/` not `/home` which i expected. Laravel dusk will take a screenshot everytime the test fails. when i look at the screenshot, it's on the right page or url as in `assertPathIs()`.

anyone can point out why is this happend? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to wait. add a pause `>pause(3000);` before `->assertPathIs('/home')` If it's still not working increase the pause value.

Answer (score 8):

You could add a waitForLocation like this:

`->waitForLocation('/home');`

before

`->assertPathIs('/home');`.

---

It is best practice to use an explicit wait (e.g.`->waitForLocation('/home');` rather than an implicit wait (e.g. `->pause(3000)`

**See:**
- http://elementalselenium.com/tips/47-waiting
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk#waiting-for-elements

Comment: How can I verify if a link is opened in a new tab , i,e  link  `target=_blank` and verify the title there?